# Could not load file or assembly 'Ninject.Web' after Install MVC Forum Nuget Package

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Created New blank MVC project and Install MVC Forum. then trying To Run solution I am getting Error

> Could not load file or assembly 'Ninject.Web, Version=3.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c7192dc5380945e7' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Ninject.Web, Version=3.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c7192dc5380945e7' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to determine why the assembly 'Ninject.Web, Version=3.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c7192dc5380945e7' could not be loaded.

after uninstall-MVC Forum package its  Working.  how to fix this issues ?

Comment: refer this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10637799/ninject-assembly-does-not-match-referenced-assembly

Answer (score 0):

You just need to uninstalled all the packages of Ninject

OR

Get it from NuGet

http://www.nuget.org/packages/Ninject.Web.Common/3.0.0.7